# Order of light calculation on scene

Tags: opengl, rendering, light, blending

Does lights (or their type) order on scene matters?

I'm working on forward renderer using OpenGL and I have different results (shadow color) depending on lights order (each light got it's own pass with additive blending)

[image]
[image]

Comment: their position does not change - only in which pass they are applied. On first screenshot orange point light is calculated in first pass, on the second it's applied in second pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used wrong order of configuring rendering pipeline:

```
bind framebuffer
set viewport & clear buffers
depth stage settings
blending settings
other rasterizer settings
```

I've moved `set viewport & clear buffers` to the end. Now everything looks the same regardless of the lighting (render pass) order.